# Emulating possessive quantifiers

Tags: .net, regex, quantifiers

Is it possible to emulate possessive quantifiers (.NET doesn’t support it) using atomic grouping (or in other way)?

Note. I found that `(x+x+)++y` can be replaced with `(?>(x+x+)+)y`, but this is just an example and I don’t know whether always `{something}@+` equals to `(?>{something}@)` (where `@` is a quantifier).

Comment: Isn't `(?>...)` the same? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Kobi: Yes. See my answer for details from the master.

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Quantifiers > More on the differences..."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yup. May I quote the master himself, Jeffrey Friedl, from page 142 of his classic [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124):

> "In one sense, possessive quantifiers are just syntactic sugar, as they can be mimicked with atomic grouping. Something like `.++` has exactly the same result as `(?>.+)`, although a smart implementation can optimize possessive quantifiers more than atomic grouping."

Comment: Amen to that. Long live Friedl the Great. +1 :)

Answer (score 11):

Nope, that's all there is to it.  Possessive quantifiers are just a convenient shorthand for atomic groups.

Now, if you were using a flavor that doesn't support atomic groups either (like JavaScript and Python), you could use a lookahead to get the same effect:

```
(?=((x+x+)+))\1y
```

A lookahead works just like an atomic group except that it doesn't consume what it matches.  So you wrap its contents in a capturing group, then use a backreference to do the consuming.